# Establishing a strategy to log data processing steps

Tags: dataset

I am building a database schema for a web application that will collect user feedback on restaurants. As the collection of user feedback grows for each restaurant, I will be analyzing it to assign properties to the restaurant record that will be exposed publicly in the web app. Some example processing algorithms I plan on implementing are:

- For each restaurant with X "up votes" from independent IP addresses, set property RECOMMENDED to TRUE.
- Merge restaurant records with equivalent NAME and ADDRESS fields.

More important than those examples, however, is the fact that I don't know exactly how I will process the data. I'm sure that once I begin receiving user feedback, I'll want to tweak my processing routines, or establish new processing steps.

It strikes me as a good idea to include in each restaurant record a list of all processing actions taken against it. **Thus, my question:**

**Are there papers or other resources that you could direct me towards that discuss best practices for how to structure logs for data processing actions in a flexible, useful structure?**

I've looked around on Google, but all the resources I could find discussed how to process log data, rather than logging the process.

Thanks in advance.